# Why do I get "Undefined variable error" when returning an array from a class?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am experiencing "Undefined variable" error when returning an array from a class, but I do not understand why this would happen.

If I `print_r($order_ids)` from within the class, there is no issue. The issue only occurs when I try to `print_r($order_ids)` from outside the class.

CLASS FUNCTIONS FILE

```
function getOrderIds($start_order, $end_order) {

    $conn = new Database();

    $sql = "SELECT order_id FROM oc_order WHERE order_status_id = '17' AND order_id BETWEEN '$start_order' AND '$end_order'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $order_ids[] = $row['order_id'];
        }
    }

    return($order_ids);

}
```

CALL

```
$order = new Order();
$order->getOrderIds($start_order, $end_order); 

print_r($order_ids);
```

RESULT

```
Notice: Undefined variable: order_ids
```

Comment: Missing: $order_ids = $order->getOrderIds($start_order, $end_order); // ?

Comment: I suggest to change `function getOrderIds($start_order, $end_order) {
` into `function getOrderIds($start_order = null, $end_order = null) {
`. In case one of the two variables are empty, you can return false.

Answer (score 2):

```
$order = new Order();
$order_ids = $order->getOrderIds($start_order, $end_order); 

print_r($order_ids);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I'm not sure why my method did not work? My understanding was that the `return` function would define $order_ids for me. Do you know where I am going wrong with my understanding of `return`?

Comment: your variable $order_ids is defined in getOrderIds function of your class, it isn't reachable outside of this function. The return of a function returns you the value of the variable, not the variable